# Haskell won't match against a list

Tags: list, haskell, pattern-matching

I want to try out some haskell and started with 99 haskell problems, currently I'm stuck at 13: Run-length encoding of a list (though my question is more general)

```
--datatype
data En a = Multiple (Int, a) | Single a | Empty
    deriving (Show)

--helper
getnum :: (Eq a9) => [a9] -> Int
getnum [] = 0
getnum (x:xs)
    | x == head xs = 1 + getnum xs
    | otherwise = 1

encodeDirect :: [a] -> [En a]
endoceDirect xxs@(x:xs)
    | getnum xxs == 1 = Single x : encodeDirect xs
    | otherwise = Multiple ((getnum xxs), x) : encodeDirect (drop (getnum xxs) xxs)
encodeDirect _ = [Empty]
```

This should give me the solution with an [Empty] at the end, but when I call encodeDirect with any kind of list/string from ghci it just falls straight through, and all I get is [Empty].

Why does `xxs@(x:xs)` not match any list?

Comment: Typo. You swapped the 'c' and 'd'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should give you at least a warning about function `endoceDirect`, which, of course, doesn't have anything to do with `encodeDirect`.

As a side note, the catch-all case is usually a bad idea,

Comment: The catch all was just to get it to run, I removed it in the final version, but I guess this is why I didn't get a warning about the typo.

Comment: Thus it being a bad idea.